# global variables and/or array of variables

Tags: calculations, fp, scoping

I'm looking for a way to obtain (in tex/latex - still difficult for me to determine the difference - I guess it should state latex) run-time defineable global variables to be used with the fp package.

I want to define a function, that each time it is invoked, creates such a variable,
and a second function that can use and/or update the value of this variable.

typical result

```
\newcommand{\defvar}[1]{%
  % var#1 := 0
  \expandafter\FPset\csname var#1\endcsname{0}%
}

\newcommand{\addvar}[2]{%
  % var#1 += #2
  \expandafter\FPadd\csname var#1\endcsname{\csname \var#1\endcsname}{#2}%
}
```

unfortunately doesn't seem to work,... 
can somebody explain my mistake ?

Answer (score 4):

You have a wrong `\var` in the definition of `\addvar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}

\newcommand{\defvar}[1]{%
  % var#1 := 0
  \expandafter\FPset\csname var#1\endcsname{0}%
}

\newcommand{\addvar}[2]{%
  % var#1 += #2
  \expandafter\FPadd\csname var#1\endcsname{\csname var#1\endcsname}{#2}%
}

% added for debugging
\newcommand{\showvar}[1]{\typeout{var "#1" is \csname var#1\endcsname}}

\defvar{x}
\showvar{x}
\addvar{x}{3}
\showvar{x}
```

Here's the output on the terminal

```
var "x" is 0
( FP-ADD )
var "x" is 3.000000000000000000
```

---

A different implementation using `expl3` and its `fp` module; I also added a convenience command `\usevar`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defvar}{m}
 {
  \fp_new:c { l_liselorev_var_#1_fp }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addvar}{mm}
 {
  % var#1 += #2
  \fp_add:cn { l_liselorev_var_#1_fp } { #2 }
 }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l_liselorev_var_#1_fp }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\showvar}{m}
 {
  \fp_show:c { l_liselorev_var_#1_fp }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defvar{x}
\showvar{x}
\addvar{x}{3}
\showvar{x}
```

The output on the terminal:

```
> 0.
<recently read> }

l.28 \showvar{x}

? 
> 3.
<recently read> }

l.30 \showvar{x}
```