# Using an array for reading and writing within Tikz loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

What is the right way of working with arrays in `\foreach` loops?  I am trying to illustrate the Tower of Hanoi problem.  I have a sequence of pairs "disk size"/"rod", and my code is supposed to draw disks on the rods placed there in accordance to my sequence.  However, there seems to be some problem with the array (I use the [`arrayjobx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/arrayjobx?lang=en) package but I am happy to switch to some other technology if it is more appropriate).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}

\begin{document}
\def\sequence{4/1,3/2,2/1,1/2}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \newarray\last

    % Initialise \last and print the rod indices
    \foreach \rod in {1, 2}{
        \last(\rod)={0};
        \node at (5 * \rod, -1) {\rod};
    }

    \foreach \size/\rod in \sequence{
        % Load \last(\rod) in variable \y
        \checklast(\rod);
        \let\l\cachedata;
        \xdef\y{\l};

        % Update \last(\rod)
        \last(\rod)={\y + 1};

        % Draw the disk
        \draw[ultra thick] (5*\rod - 0.5*\size, \y)--(5*\rod + 0.5*\size, \y);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the following result:

[image]

while expected is:

[image]

Tower of Hanoi is just a toy example; the point is that my real case requires non-sequential reads and writes to several arrays within a `\foreach` loop.

Comment: Note that `arrayjob` is not compatible with LaTeX and `arrayjobx` should be used

Comment: Did you have a look at [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/towers-of-hanoi/)?

Comment: Thank you egreg, I tried `arrayjobx` but that hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you moospit, I checked that example.  I am afraid it doesn't use arrays (indeed, it is possible to avoid using arrays in this toy example).  In my real case it is impossible to avoid some sort of memory.

Comment: IIRC, tikz arrays are write once constructs.  For true random access you need to use \csname.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212715/global-variables-and-or-array-of-variables for example.

Comment: Thank you @JohnKormylo, I attempted to use \csname.  However, I somehow fail to use mathematical operators with elements of my arrays.  Here's a minimal example:

`\expandafter\def\csname last@array@1\endcsname{0}`

`\def\y{\csname last@array@1\endcsname}`

`\def\newy{\y + 1}`

`\newy`

This prints "0+ 1" instead of just "1".  I guess there are some issues with data types?  I am afraid I have very little idea of how TeX/LaTeX compilers treat variables.

Comment: You need to use \pgfmathparse{\y + 1} and \let\newy=\pgfmathresult.  The array is storing text, not numbers.

Comment: If you don't have that many elements in the array, you could use count registers.  Just surround them with \bgroup ... \egroup to preserve the current values on the stack.

Comment: Thank you @JohnKormylo, \pgfmathparse trick fixed the remaining issues.

Answer (score 6):

I define three macros:

- `\gset` : for "global set". To use like this `\gset data[2]=3`
- `\get` : for "get". To use like this `\get data[2]`
- `\ginc` : for "global increment". To use like this `\ginc data[1]+=2`

One example of use :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
  % set the value
  \def\gset #1[#2]=#3{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname #1#2\endcsname{#3}
  }
  % get the value
  \def\get #1[#2]{%
    \csname #1#2\endcsname
  }
  % increment the value
  \def\ginc #1[#2]+=#3{%
    \pgfmathparse{\get #1[#2]+#3}%
    \gset #1[#2]=\pgfmathresult
  }

\begin{document}
  % the sequence
  \def\sequence{7/1,6/3,5/1,4/1,3/2,2/3,1/3}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=4mm, line cap=round,xscale=3,brown!30]
    % init colors
    \foreach[count=\j] \c in {red,green,blue,orange,pink,purple,gray}
      \gset col[\j]={\c};
    \edef\numdisks{\j}
    % init positions and draw support
    \foreach \j in {1,2,3}{
      \gset pos[\j]=0
      \draw (\j,-.5) -- +(0,3);
    }
    \draw (.5,-.5) -- +(3,0);

    % draw
    \foreach[count=\k] \i/\j in \sequence{
      \draw[draw={\get col[\i]}] (\j,\get pos[\j]) +(-.4*\i/\numdisks,0) -- +(.4*\i/\numdisks,0);
      \ginc pos[\j]+={.5}
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for your comments.  With your help, I managed to figure out how to implement this using the \csname mechanism:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\sequence{4/1,3/2,2/1,1/2}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    % Initialise "last" and print the rod indices
    \foreach \rod in {1, 2}{
        \expandafter\xdef\csname last@array@\rod\endcsname{0}
        \node at (5 * \rod, -1) {\rod};
    }   

    \foreach \size/\rod in \sequence{
        % Load last[\rod] in variable \y
        \pgfmathparse{\csname last@array@\rod\endcsname}
        \let\y=\pgfmathresult

        % Update last[\rod]
        \pgfmathparse{\y + 1}
        \let\newy=\pgfmathresult;
        \expandafter\xdef\csname last@array@\rod\endcsname{\newy};

        % Draw the disk
        \draw[ultra thick] (5*\rod - 0.5*\size, \y)--(5*\rod + 0.5*\size, \y);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```